# CDO.Message.1 error '80040213' with Google Address

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, cdo.message

Been having an issue trying to move our ASP page CDO over to gmail. It's about to drive me crazy. I've done some exhaustive searching and I think my code is right but I still get the dreaded: CDO.Message.1 error '80040213' The transport failed to connect to the server. on oMail.Send. Any thoughts would be much appreciated. I'm beginning to think it may be a server firewall issue.

```
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
Const cdoAnonymous = 0 
Const cdoBasic = 1 
Const cdoNTLM = 2 
Set oMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic 
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "info@domain.com"
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

oMail.From = "info@domain.com"
oMail.To = "someone@domain.com"
oMail.Bcc = ""
'oMail.To = ""
oMail.Subject = ""

oMail.HTMLBody = "<font size='2' face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>"

oMail.HTMLBody = oMail.HTMLBody + "Name: <b>"& request.form("Name")&"</b><br>"
oMail.HTMLBody = oMail.HTMLBody + "Phone: <b>"& request.form("Phone")&"</b><br>"
oMail.HTMLBody = oMail.HTMLBody + "Email: <b>"& request.form("Email")&"</b><br>"
oMail.HTMLBody = oMail.HTMLBody + "Best Time to Call: <b>"& request.form("BestTime")&"</b><br>"
oMail.HTMLBody = oMail.HTMLBody + "Question/Comment: <b>"& request.form("Comment")&"</b><br>"

oMail.HTMLBody = oMail.HTMLBody + "</font>"
oMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

oMail.Send 

Set oMail = Nothing 
Set oMailConfig = Nothing
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated. I've tried all the Google smtp ports 25,465, and 567. What am I missing?

Comment: You mention `port 567` but have you tried `port 587`?

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [Google's own instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665119,1665162);

**Standard configuration instructions:**

> **Incoming Mail (POP3) Server - requires SSL:**     pop.gmail.com
>   **Use SSL:** Yes
>   **Port:** 995
>   **Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS or SSL:**   smtp.gmail.com
>
> > **Use Authentication:** Yes
> >     **Port for TLS/STARTTLS:** 587
> >     **Port for SSL:** 465
>
> **Server timeouts**     Greater than 1 minute, we recommend 5
>   **Full Name or Display Name:**   [your name]
>   **Account Name or User Name:**   your full email address (including @gmail.com or @your_domain.com)
>   **Email Address:**   your email address (username@gmail.com or username@your_domain.com)
>   **Password:**    your Gmail password

I would also check your server has dns resolution to `smtp.gmail.com` and check your firewall which maybe blocking port 465, as a test try connecting without SSL to see if you can connect on 25 (see this article - [Unable to send emails using gmail smtp server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7e558cdf-25b9-415a-b6db-7815b0326099/unable-to-send-emails-using-gmail-smtp-server?forum=accessdev)

Suggestion for google:

> If you're having trouble sending mail but you've confirmed that encryption is active for SMTP in your mail client, try to configure your SMTP server on a different port (465 or 587).

Comment: Hey sorry guys. I must have mistyped port 587. I've tried all three ports with and without SSL enabled. I've confirmed the Google login and that SMTP is enabled on the account. Starting to think it may be the server.

What's the best way to confirm the server has a resolution to smtp.gmail.com if its actually hosted through another company? We are able to do smtp through a SmarterMail server, BUT the email does not deliver to all the addresses. No error messages, just no delivery.

Thanks for the help!